# General equation to the straight line

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Is the general equation to the straight line $Ax + By + C = 0$, or $Ax + By = C$. I have met both definitions in different books, and they obviously confer the same idea, but at most times it might be tricky dealing with both forms. For when equation 1 is algebraically rearanged we will find it to state that $Ax + By = -C$, which is different from our coveted result. This can serve to a disadvantage when substituting the constants for numbers. How am I to deal with these differences?

Comment: Notations in many formulas, like the distance of a point from a line, follow the ax+by+c=0 format.

Comment: This is a very subtle case of different variations (definitions) being important in different cases. As you go along, you'll figure out which ones are good for which purposes.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer here. I personally prefer a different form, $y= mx + c$, since it helps you think in terms of the slope and the intercept of the line. The key is to stay consistent in your writing, your code, or whatever you are trying to do :)

Comment: If we're picky, _neither_ is correct, because context about the meaning of each symbol is omitted. <> If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are real numbers and $(x, y)$ denote Cartesian coordinates in the plane, then _both_ are correct, though "not for the same $C$."

Answer (score 3):

There are many forms describing a line. Some have more specific uses, and some are more general.

Between the two mentioned I think the first one is more common because it is used with homogeneous coordinates.

If the homogeneous coordinates (coefficients) of  a line are $L = (A,B,C)$ and the coordinates of a point $P = (x,y,1)$ then the point is incident to the line when $L \cdot P = 0$ or expanded as

$$(A,B,C) \cdot (x,y,1) = 0 $$

$$ A x + B y + C = 0 $$

which is an equation of the lines since it is valid for all points $P=(x,y,1)$ that belong to the line.

Note that using the $(A,B,C)$ coordinates for lines, you can find the point where two lines intersect (in homogeneous coordinates) with

$$ P = L_1 \times L_2 $$

or the line  that connects two points

$$ L = P_1 \times P_2 $$

where $\times$ is the regular 3-vector cross product.

Here are some other equations for a line

- $(-\sin \psi) x + (\cos \psi )y = d$ for the line with direction angle $\psi$ and perpendicular distance from the origin $d$.
- $\tfrac{x}{a} + \tfrac{y}{b} = 1$ Line with *x*-intercept $a$ and *y*-intercept $b$
- $y = m x + b$ Standard *y*-intercept $b$ and slope $m$
- $(x,y) = (1-t) (x_1,y_1) + t ( x_2,y_2) $ Parametric line between points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ with parameter $t$
- $(x,y) = (x_0,y_0) + t (u,v)$ Ray starting at $(x_0,y_0)$ in the direction of $(u,v)$.

There are probably a lot more than the above. As I said, some are useful at specific cases and some are more general.